# 'more than once' and 'many times'

Tags: word-order

Are 'more than once' and 'many times' interchangeable? Do they have the same or similar sense?
In addition, I don't know where to put them in a sentense. Where do you usually put them in the sentence?

I want to use something similar to 'more then once' in a sense of "many times" in my speech. But I would like to say an idiom or a phraseological unit with the meaning of 'many times'.

> This law firm advised oil and gas companies *more than once* [many times] on the anticorruption and fraud issues.

Comment: The two can actually be used in combination, if you wanted to emphasize that the warnings had been repeated on multiple occasions over time. _This law firm advised oil and gas companies more than once – in fact, many times – on the anticorruption and fraud issues._ I wouldn't overuse that phrasing, but it can be found on the web and [in a few books](https://www.google.com/#q=%22more+than+once+in+fact+many+times%22&tbm=bks&start=0).

Comment: Ok. They can be used in combination. By the way, I didn't mean "warnings". Actually, the law firm provides professional advice or recommendations for clients.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These two expressions *can* have similar meanings, but do not necessarily have them. *More than once* could mean only  *twice*, and *many times* always means more than that.. If you wish to convey the message of *many* times, then use that expression, or say exactly how many times they advised the companies.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Where do you think I should write 'many times' in my example? Have I chosen the correct place to write it in the sentence?

Comment: I often use "several" to mean more than once or twice, but less than "many".

Comment: @Humbulani. I'd place it where you did, after 'oil and gas companies. There are other possibilities, but that's my preference. It's also possible, and clear, after 'law firm'.

Comment: Interesting... In French, "more than once" (*"plus d'une fois"*) always means "many times" (a kind of litotes), except when used for a frequency ("more than once a week"). If said "I've done it more than once... Twice, actually." in French, it would sound like a joke.